# Checking message query by actor in between calculations in scala/akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor, that when he receives one message he starts to do come calculations in a loop, and he does them for some time (like 100 times he does the same). Now I need him to react to other mesages that may come ASAP. The best way would be to add some instruction in his loop like "if there is a message in queue react and then return here" but I haven't seen such functionality.

I thought that actor could send message to himself instead of doing a loop, then such messages would be queued at the end and he would react to other ones in between, but I've heard that communication is bad (much more time consuming than calculations) and don't know if communication with self counts as such.

My question is what do you think about such solution and do you have anyother ideas how to handle communication inbetween calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Time-consuming computation should not be done in the main receive method as it reduces responsiveness of the system. Put the computation in a blocking
`Future` or `Task` or other asynchronous object, and send a message to the actor when the computation completes. The actor can continue to process messages ASAP while the computation continues on a different thread.

This gets more complicated if the actor needs to modify the computation while it is running (in response to messages) but the solution depends on what the computation is and what kind of modification is needed, so it isn't really possible to give a general answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general in Akka you want to limit the amount of work done "per unit" where a unit in this case:

- an actor processing a message
- work done in a `Future`/`Task` or a callback of the same

Overlong work units can easily limit the responsiveness of the entire system by consuming a thread.  For tasks which aren't consuming CPU but are blocked waiting for I/O, those can be executed in a different thread pool, but for doing some CPU-consuming work, that doesn't really help.

So the broad approach, if you're doing a loop, is to suspend the loop's state into a message and send it to yourself.  It introduces a small performance hit (the latency of constructing the message, sending it to yourself (a guaranteed-to-be local send), and destructuring it is likely going to be on the order of microseconds when the system is otherwise idle), but can improve overall system latency.

For example, imagine we have an actor which will calculate the `n`th fibonacci number.  I'm implementing this using Akka Typed, but the broad principle applies in Classic:

```scala
object Fibonacci {
  sealed trait Command

  case class SumOfFirstN(n: Int, replyTo: ActorRef[Option[Long]]) extends Command

  private object Internal {
    case class Iterate(i: Int, a: Int, b: Int)  extends Command
    val initialIterate = Iterate(1, 0, 1)
  }

  case class State(waiting: SortedMap[Int, Set[ActorRef[Option[Long]]]]) {
    def behavior: Behavior[Command] =
      Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
        msg match {
          case SumOfFirstN(n, replyTo) =>
            if (n < 1) {
              replyTo ! None
              Behaviors.same
            } else {
              if (waiting.isEmpty) {
                context.self ! Internal.initialIterate
              }

              val nextWaiting =
                waiting.updated(n, waiting.get(n).fold(Set(replyTo))(_.incl(replyTo))
              copy(waiting = nextWaiting).behavior
            }

          case Internal.Iterate(i, a, b) =>
            // the ith fibonacci number is b, the (i-1)th is a
            if (waiting.rangeFrom(i).isEmpty) {
              // Nobody waiting for this run to complete
              if (waiting.nonEmpty) {
                context.self ! Internal.initialIterate
              }

              Behaviors.same
            } else {
              var nextWaiting = waiting
              var nextA = a
              var nextB = b

              (1 to 10).foreach { x =>
                val next = nextA + nextB

                nextWaiting.get(x + i).foreach { waiters =>
                  waiters.foreach(_ ! Some(next))
                }

                nextWaiting = nextWaiting.removed(x + i)
                nextA = nextB
                nextB = next
              }

              context.self ! Internal.Iterate(i + 10, nextA, nextB)
              copy(waiting = nextWaiting)
            }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Note that multiple requests (if sufficiently temporally close) for the same number will only be computed once, and temporally close requests for intermediate results will result in no extra computation.

Comment: With all respect I think this is a rather narrow view of the kind of systems that Akka can be used for. There are plenty of applications that require large chunks of indivisible computation that can still be effectively managed and controlled with Akka. In fact the ability of Akka to continue to be responsive in this environment is one of its strong points.

Comment: This "solution" is basically a software re-implementation of the thread scheduling algorithm in the operating system, and is almost certainly less effective and with greater overhead than the OS. If you have a system that requires 100% of the CPU of all the cores then adding overhead like this is not the solution. If not, the OS will be able to schedule the Akka message threads often enough to maintain responsiveness even if you have other threads that perform large chunks of computation.

Comment: You can run long CPU-intensive tasks on threads outside the main dispatcher.  My experience with doing that (leaving thread scheduling to the OS) has not been positive, in terms of dramatically increased thread starvation in the main dispatcher.

Comment: Feels like an issue with your particular OS/scheduler rather than a general problem, since you shouldn't get thread starvation unless the starved threads have somehow been given a lower priority.

Comment: Any time the OS schedules a thread that's not in the main Akka dispatcher, it violates a subtle assumption implicitly made by Akka that if any of the threads in that dispatcher are scheduled, all of them are scheduled.  Now if there's very little to be done in that dispatcher, it's no problem (and you can mitigate this by shrinking the main dispatcher by the expected number of executing threads in the other dispatcher), no starvation occurs (and by starvation I'm referring to something more general than what a thread starvation detector detects).

Comment: The broad problem with any preemptive OS scheduler is that while it minimizes the overhead of the task switch itself, the heuristics used in deciding whether to switch tasks are cruder than what you can get from knowledge of the domain (and that domain knowledge also means that you know how much state actually needs to be saved as part of the task switch, which in some cases allows for a more efficient task switch).

Comment: If OS schedulers were at all close to being better than a cooperative yield model, we'd be using thread-per-request and no one would bother with green threads.

Comment: You obviously have come across some issues with the systems you are using, but it cannot possibly be the case that  "Any time the OS schedules a thread that's not in the main Akka dispatcher, it violates a subtle assumption implicitly made by Akka" because every system that Akka runs on has non-Akka threads. In my application there are non-Akka processes doing heavy network and data processing and Akka only uses a few percent of the CPU and runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to delegate the task, using for eg:`Future`, and use a separate ExecutionContext with a `fixed-pool-size` (configurable in `application.conf`) equal to the number of CPUs (or cores) so that the computations are done efficiently using the available cores. As mentioned by @Tim, you could notify the main actor once the computation is complete.

Another option is to make another actor behind a router do the computation while restricting the number of routees to the number of CPUs.

A simplistic sample:

```
object DelegatingSystem extends App {

  val sys = ActorSystem("DelegatingSystem")

  case class TimeConsuming(i: Int)
  case object Other

  class Worker extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case message =>
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        log.info(s"$self computed long $message")
    }
  }

  class Delegator extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    //Set the number of routees to be equal to #of cpus
    val router: ActorRef = context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(2).props(Props[Worker]))

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case message:TimeConsuming => router ! message
      case _ =>
        log.info("process other messages")
    }
  }

  val delegator = sys.actorOf(Props[Delegator])
  delegator ! TimeConsuming(1)
  delegator ! Other
  delegator ! TimeConsuming(2)
  delegator ! Other
  delegator ! TimeConsuming(3)
  delegator ! Other
  delegator ! TimeConsuming(4)
}
```